# SQL query to merge the data based on boolean column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to merge the data based on a Boolean column

Original data:

```
FName LName Status
------------------
x     y     1
x     y     0
a     b     1
t     t     1
u     e     1
t     t     1
a     b     0
```

End result I want to achieve

```
FName LName Yes  No
-------------------
x     y     1    1
a     b     1    1
t     t     2    0
u     e     1    0
```

This is what I tried but it didn't get me what I wanted -

```
SELECT
    [FirstName], [LastName], COUNT(*) AS No
FROM 
    [dbo].[tablename]  
GROUP BY
    [FirstName], [LastName], [Status] 
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1 AND Status = 0 

UNION  

SELECT 
    [FirstName], [LastName], COUNT(*) AS Yes
FROM 
    [dbo].[tablename]  
GROUP BY
    [FirstName], [LastName], [Status] 
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1 AND Status = 1
```

I am sure there must be an easy way to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need `SUM` and a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT  FName,
        LName,
        SUM(CASE WHEN [Status] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Yes,
        SUM(CASE WHEN [Status] = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) No
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY FName,
         LName;
```

Comment: Thank you so much , just a quick question , how would I calculate the percentage , want something like (no/total requests made)*100

Comment: @learner999 for this, it would help to know what version of SQL Server you are using

Comment: SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 0):

Possible way is

```
select [FirstName],[LastName], 
   sum(0+[Status]) as Yes,
   count([Status]) - sum(0+[Status]) as No
from [dbo].[tablename]  
group by [FirstName],[LastName]
```

`0+[Status]` implicitly converts bit [Status] to integer.